# Heap dump on JRE 6 (Windows) without JDK

Tags: java, memory-leaks, heap-memory, dump

Is there a way to create a heap dump on a remote machine without JDK installed?

I can't change the installation / settings and it's running on Windows.
So I have pnly access to commandline tools.

Problem is that a Java app on a remote machine freezes (no out of memory exception so -XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError is useless) and we need to create a dump.

```
-XX:+HeapDumpOnCtrlBreak
```

is no option too, because it's not supported anymore on JDK6+.

JMX is not allowed due to security reasons.

Any Ideas? Thank you for your help!

Edit:

- Windows
- No JDK
- No JMX

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I solved the problem.

You have to "patch" your JRE with some files of the JDK (the same version of course - if you are running jre6uXX you need the corresponding files from jdk6uXX )

Copy the following files:

- \JDK6uXX\bin\attach.dll --> %JAVAJRE_HOME%\bin\
- \JDK6uXX\bin\jmap.exe  --> %JAVAJRE_HOME%\bin\
- \JDK6uXX\lib\tools.jar --> %JAVAJRE_HOME%\lib\

No files are overwritten, JRE shouldn't be affected by this.

Now you can use jmap just fine to take dumps ;-)

I appreciate your help! Bye

Comment: When I try that, I get a message saying `The procedure entry pont JLI_CmdToArgs could not be located in the dynamic link library jli.dll`

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to use `jmap -dump:liv,format=b,file=app.dump` on the command line. You can use `jps -lvm` to find the process id.

An alternative is to connect to it to `jvisualvm`  This will take the dump and analyse it for you.  You can also use this tool to read a dump written by jmap so you may end up using it anyway.

Where `jvisualvm` struggles is for large heap dumps i.e. more than about half you main memory size.  I have found using YourKit to handle larger dumps and also give more useful information. An evaluation license might be all you need to diagnose this.

> jmx is not allowed due to security reasons

In that case, you can't do this remotely, unless you use `YourKit` or some other commercial profiler.

Comment: as I said no jdk available :)

Comment: @98percentmonkey do you mean on any machine, or just the machine running the program.  If you have a JDK of the same version on any machine on your network, you can do it remotely.

Comment: on the running machine, but sadly no JMX, too :(

Comment: @98percentmonkey if you can't use JMX, or install a JDK, you will have to use a commercial profiler.

Comment: @98percentmonkey The only other option is to reproduce the problem on a machine you have a JDK on. If security has locked down the machine, by design there is no easy way around it.

Comment: Thank you for your help anyway. Sadly XX:+HeapDumpOnCtrlBreak is gone, this option would have been useful.

Answer (score 1):

You have start your application with jmx console enabled in a port to debug your application. Execute jconsole and connect to the port which you have enabled for debugging. You can also use of jmap to collect heapdump.

Comment: jmx is not allowed due to security reasons

Answer (score 1):

[JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) has a command line utility `bin/jpdump` that can take an HPROF heap dump. There is no need to install JDK. There is also no need to run the GUI installer of JProfiler, just extract the ZIP distribution and execute jpdump on the command line.

Disclaimer: My company develops JProfiler.

---

**Update 2016-06-23**

As of JProfiler 9.2, jpdump and jpenable run with Java 6 as well.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to execute jpdump with arguments? 
A dump via .bat would be very good. jpdump <Prozessid> or something like that.

Comment: Yes, `jpdump -p [pid]` works like that. If no such argument is given, jpdump is interactive and lists all Java processes.

Comment: Great tool, but sadly It needs JDK8 and jprofiler 7 (which could work with jdk6/7) doesn't have a jpdump.exe :(

Comment: The JProfiler 8 GUI works with a Java 7 JRE as well. However, the Windows ZIP archive includes a private JRE, so you do not need to install a JRE of a particular version. As for the profiled JVM, JProfiler 8 works with Java 5 and higher and jpdump works with Java 6 and higher.

Comment: I meant that jpdump.exe doesn't run with JRE 1.6.
And a standalone jpdump.exe would be great, because I'm very restricted about the file size which should be transferred.  
I tried jpdump.exe, jpprofiler.jar and the lib dir to run on jre 6 without success

Comment: jpdump indeed needs Java 7 to run. You would have to transfer the entire JProfiler archive to the remote machine.

Comment: sadly that's no option at the moment, but thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use jvisualvm, just enable jmx port and connect to your application, then you will be able to generate a heap file.

You can do that by adding the following parameters:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8484
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

Then You need to add your tomcat process manually, So `right click on you localhost node -> Add JMX Connection -> type your port -> OK`.

Your tomcat process will be listed in under localhost node.

Comment: JMX is not allowed due to security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

```
     jmap -dump:format=b,file=snapshot.jmap  
     process-pid
```

Regardless of how the Java VM was started, the jmap tool will produce a head dump snapshot, in the above example in a file called snapshot.jmap. The jmap output files should contain all the primitive data, but will not include any stack traces showing where the objects have been created.

Comment: no access to jdk on the machine like said above, sorry