# Desktop application does not work properly on end-user machine but it does on local

Tags: java, io, apache-poi

I've developed a desktop application using Java Swing. Essentially the application process excel spreadsheets, store them in a MySQL database and display everything inserted/updated in that database and what else it's already in it.

The problem is the following, the importing function of the spreadsheets does not work on the end-user machine. Everything is working fine when I'm on my dev machine using a local database but when I change the settings for the live VM's database the importing function will just stop at some point in my code. I've added a logger and it seems it stops when my method for importing tries to create an XSSFWorkbook object from the given file path. Again, everything working on local, but not on end-user machine. The difficulty in debugging this is that I do not have access to the network where the VM is located, so I have to deploy every time a build for my user to run it on their machine where it has access to that specific network.

Code of the method:

```
void importSpreadsheet(String path) throws IOException {
    ...
    InputStream ExcelFileToRead = new FileInputStream(path);

    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFileToRead); // logger stops just above this line, no exception/error thrown
    ...}
```

More confusing is that in previous builds, the function was working fine on the end-user machine. The database user has enough permissions, and the user has admin rights. I have all the required dependencies, and I tried different versions of Apache-POI but the result is just the same.

Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: it just stops? No errors? Are you trying to catch and log exceptions at all? Or inserting any other kind of logging to try and get into the guts of what's going wrong? If it's an environment problem I'd be looking towards issues like filesystem permissions, correct usage of paths, network access / routing, that kind of thing. But it's only a guess, without actually getting any proper error detail.

Comment: P.S. This appears, from the code shown, to have nothing at all to do with MySQL, not sure why you tagged that? Only tag something if it's directly relevant to the problem, not just because your app uses it somewhere else. Same, arguably, goes for the Swing GUI library. Sounds like it would be better tagged as Java and apache-poi, and maybe something to do with I/O

Comment: @ADyson yes the method just terminates. Yes I do catch and log everything as follow:

 try {
            InputStream ExcelFileToRead = new FileInputStream(path);
            logger.info(ExcelFileToRead.toString());
            logger.info("Initialising input stream");
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFileToRead);
            ......
   catch (IOException e) {
            logger.info(e.getMessage());
        } catch (org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException e) {
            logger.info(e.getMessage());
}

Comment: The log file stops writing at "Initialising input stream"

Comment: perhaps it's throwing some other type of exception which you aren't logging (not an IO exception or InvalidFormatException). You should make it log _all_ exceptions. Or, perhaps the file path is wrong/inaccessible in some way and it's not throwing an error but just re-trying for ever or something like that. Have you checked the path?

Comment: Is the program crashing? Or hanging? If it's hanging, ask it for a thread dump to see what's going on (method differs between OS and JVM, so just google java thread dump + what you're using)

Comment: @ADyson I switched the catch block to Exception e, still nothing on the logger, also the path is just fine.

Comment: @Gagravarr I'm really constrained by the fact that my end-user has just the jre embedded in the build folder so I cannot use any tools from jdk. I tried to "patch" the jre with jmap's files from jdk folder like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30025936/heap-dump-on-jre-6-windows-without-jdk but it does not work.